# Schrödinger eigenfunctions are bounded

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, schrodinger-operators

Let $V:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+ *}$ a real positive function such that $\displaystyle \lim_{ x \to \pm\infty} V(x)= +\infty $.

Then the Schrödinger operator $H=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)$ has compact resolvant, in particular it has a pure discrete spectrum 
$(\lambda_i)_{i\geq 0}$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{i\to +\infty} \lambda_i = + \infty$. Associated to each eigenvalue, there is an eigenfunction $\phi_i\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, ie
 $$-\phi_i''(x)+V(x)\phi_i(x)=\lambda_i \phi_i(x), \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R} $$

satisfying  $||\phi_i||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}=1$,

**My question is:** Are eigenfunctions uniformly bounded? i.e. Does exist $M>0$ such that for all $n\geq 0$,

$$|| \phi_i ||_\infty <M $$

Comment: the eigenfunctions could have a square-integrable singularity, couldn't they?

Comment: Relevant for free Schrödinger problem on manifolds of dimension at least two: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1087575454

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: No, being solutions to an ODE, they have a second derivative that is locally integrable (so in particular are continuous).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there won't be a uniform bound on all eigenfunctions simultaneously. If $[a,b]$ is a short interval with Dirichlet boundary conditions $y(a)=y(b)=0$ and constant potential $V=c$, then the ground state (normalized) eigenfunction
$$
\phi(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{b-a}}\, \sin\pi\frac{x-a}{b-a}
$$
is quite large pointwise.

A very high steep potential wall has approximately the same effect as a Dirichlet boundary condition, so we can easily cook up a $V$ where we are close to this situation infinitely many times, with arbitrarily small interval lengths.

Comment: The bound M  of the question is  a bound $M = M(V)$.  For your example,there is such an M:  $M = \sqrt{2/(b-a)}$, also valid for the higher eigenvalues which are this M multiplied by $sin(k\pi (x-a)/(b-a))$, $k=2,3,...$ so your `counterexample' is in fact an example of this bounded phenomenon.

Comment: @RichardMontgomery: You completely misunderstood my example. I construct a whole line potential $V$ that contains parts that look like $V=c_n$ on $I_n=(a_n,b_n)$, $V\gg c_n$ on two intervals of length $L_n\gg 1$ to the left and right of $I_n$. This will have approximately the eigenfunctions I stated, but for arbitrarily small $b_n-a_n$.

Comment: Yes.  I did not read your last sentence Christian.   Using your  trick I see you can do as you say, having a potential which is non-negative, piecewise constant, and  zero on a countable collection of intervals $I_j$ whose size tends to zero.  There will be eigenfunctions supported on each interval and their max will go like $\sqrt{2/|I_j|}$.

Comment: If one imposes analyticity to V, then what?

Comment: @RichardMontgomery: I don't really have a precise answer, but I can't imagine that having any consequences on this issue. In fact, maybe even a totally explicit (and real analytic) version of my example such as $V(x)=(2+\sin x^2) e^{x^2}$ would work.

Answer (score 2):

This is Christian Remling's answer. I am just adding this to   make it   more explicit
and underline what he wrote, so vote him `up' not me.  Take the potential $V(x)$ to be zero on a countable collection of disjoint intervals
$I_j$, $j =1, 2, \ldots$ with $\lim_j |I_j| = 0$, and take $V$ postive and tending to infinity on the complement of these intervals. 
For  example, if we assume that  $\Sigma_j |I_j| < 1$ we could place all the intervals within
the interval $[1,2]$ and take $V(x) = x^2 +1 $ on the complement of the $I_j$.
The ```ground state for $I_j$'', which I will call $\psi_j$, and for which    Christian writes down a formula
when $I_j = (a,b)$,  is zero outside of $I_j$, vanishes on the endpoints of $I_j$, forms the positive
arc of a sine wave inside $I_j$,  has    maximum $\sqrt{2/| I_j|}$ occuring  at the midpoint of $I_j$, and
has $L_2$ norm equal to $1$.     Since the $|I_j| \to 0$ the maxima of these $\psi_j$ tend to $\infty$ with $j$.[image: sketch of potential]